# change elements in a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, swap, element

I want to check elements in a list then if they are bigger then the next one then swap their places.  I can not go further than the code below

```
change [] =[]
change (x:xs) 
       | x > head xs = change (head xs : x : tail xs) 
       | otherwise = change xs  

main = do 
 print $ change [3,2,4] 
 -- expected [2,3,4]
```

Comment: you should go through your history and mark the best answers "answered" so the kind folks who answered your questions can get internet points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 base cases that you need to consider: 1) an empty list, 2) a list with one element, and 3) a list with two or more elements.  If you consider these three cases individually, the function is pretty easy to define:

```
change :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
change [] = []
change (x:[]) = [x]
change (x1:x2:xs)
    | x1 > x2 = x2 : change (x1 : xs)
    | otherwise = x1 : change (x2 : xs)
```

**EDIT** As @kqr has pointed out, you can rearrange this into

```
change :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
change (x1:x2:xs)
    | x1 > x2 = x2 : change (x1 : xs)
    | otherwise = x1 : change (x2 : xs)
change other = other
```

Comment: And if you allow yourself to reorder the definitions, you can merge the first two cases into `change other = other`.

Comment: @bheklilr & kqr Thanks.  In change  when input is :[4,5,2,3] the out put would be [4,2,3,5]. Do you know what if I wanted to have [2,3,4,5] as an out put with the same input?

Comment: @Amir If you're wanting to sort the list, use the `sort` function in `Data.List`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
change [] =[]
change [x] = [x]
change (x:xs) 
       | x > head xs = (head xs) : change (x : tail xs) 
       | otherwise = x : (change xs)
```

You lose the head of the array in the otherwise case.